# Need a simple tool for drawing arrows and labels

Tags: ms-word, annotations, ms-office, photoshop, diagram

I am trying to do a mock up technical guide with bunch of screenshot and arrows along with labels numbering each arrow.

I am look for a tool that allows me to draw arrows (I know I can do that with microsoft word) and put up numbers labeling each arrow (that is more work to do it in word), so I wonder if there is already an out-of-the-box program that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do more efficiently in regards to creating documentation. If you need to do alot of diagraming then MS Visio is the program you desire.

[Click Here](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/wireframe_annotations_in_visio_special_deliverable_11)
for a comprehensive tutorial for doing numbered arrow labels in the event you are referencing diagraming.